# Show content using ajax on click of image co-ordinates and relevant section is displayed

Tags: asp.net, html, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am working on ASP.net2.0 application using C#. Html 5.0 version used in this project.

I have a image where co-ordinates are defined and click on each co-ordinates of image corresponding section data should be visible.

for example if #service is clicked section `"<section class="service">"` should be displayed.
 if #new_generation is clicked then section `<section class="new_generation">` should be displayed.

and it should load using ajax.

```
 <section role="parallax" class="parallax cf">                      
    <map name="home_menu">
        <area class="selected" shape="poly" coords="140,0,0,105,85,105,225,0" href="#supplier" alt="SUPPLIER">
        <area shape="poly" coords="227,0,87,105,172,105,312,0" href="#service" alt="FULL SERVICE CARRIER">
        <area shape="poly" coords="314,0,174,105,259,105,399,0" href="#new_generation" alt="NEW GENERATION AIRLINE">
        <area shape="poly" coords="401,0,261,105,346,105,486,0" href="#air_freight" alt="AIR FREIGHT CARRIER">
        <area shape="poly" coords="488,0,348,105,433,105,573,0" href="#charter" alt="CHARTER AIRLINE">
        <area shape="poly" coords="575,0,435,105,520,105,660,0" href="#cargo" alt="CARGO & LOGISTICS COMPANY">
        <area shape="poly" coords="662,0,522,105,607,105,747,0" href="#hotel" alt="HOTEL GROUP">
        <area shape="poly" coords="749,0,609,105,694,105,834,0" href="#events" alt="EVENTS ORGANISER">
    </map>
</section>


<section class="home_menu_tabs">
    <section class="supplier selected"></section>
    <section class="service">
        Service Content Here comes from database, should loads using Ajax
    </section>
    <section class="new_generation">
    New Generation Content Here comes from database, should loads using Ajax
    </section>
    <section class="air_freight"></section>
    <section class="charter"></section>
    <section class="cargo"></section>
    <section class="hotel"></section>
    <section class="events"></section>
</section>
```

Please help with the jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the section by clicking on any map area

This will help

```
$(function(){

    var sections = $('.home_menu_tabs section');
    sections.hide();
    $('map').on('click', 'area', function(){
        sections.hide();
        var href =$(this).prop('href');
        var sectionClass = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('#')+1);
        //your ajax code to load content.
        $('.'+sectionClass).show();
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried script and it is not working. Please can you help me fixing the issue

Comment: What is not working. Showing section or loading content from ajax.